# MySQL rollback when auto_commit is on

Tags: mysql

by mistake I fired an update query and all the records in the table in dat field got updated and also cannot rollback as auto_commit is on.

Is there any other way to retrieve the records?

Comment: This is why using non-autocommit transactions is handy, especially when manually entering queries. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can `rollback` a query/transaction once it's been commited *(and, here, it has)* : the old data has been replaced by the new one, and has disappeared.

As possible solutions :

- If possible, depending on the update you did, there might be a way to revert that update ?
- Else, I hope you have frequent backups, and know how to restore them *(to a temporary database, if necessary, to extract the informations you need, and re-import it into your production database "by had")*...

Comment: If you restore it to your production database, yes ;; but a solution could be to restore that backup to another database ; and, then, extract only the data your need from that temporary restored database, to import those manually to your production database *(I didn't say it would be easy...)*

Comment: ya i know will try figuring out if your solution works..thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get the records but they are in the state of the last update. Rollback does not work, cause the transaction is closed already. (auto_commit on).

Answer (score 0):

If you've got [binary logging](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-log.html) enabled, you could restore the database from backups, then extract whatever changes were between the backuptime and your bad query from the binary log and re-apply them to the database.